# Real Analysis homework hint

Tags: real-analysis

a) Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be continuous. Prove that there exists a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=c$.

b) Does this result still hold for continuous function $f: [0,\infty )\rightarrow[0,\infty)$? Either prove it or provide counter-example.

Comment: What do you learn about continuous functions? Can you draw a picture to convince yourself that (a) is true?

Comment: Yes. Is it like proving the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Exactly, you can use IVT. A hint is to try $f(x) - x$.

Comment: Consider the function $g(x) = f(x)-x$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $g(a)=f(a)-a\geq 0$ and $g(b)=f(b)-b\leq0$. By IVT, there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $g(c)=c$. That is $f(c)=c$. Is this proof okay?

Comment: Here the IVT implies that there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $g(c)=0$, not $g(c)=c$.

Comment: Okay I'll fix the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, consider the function
$$g(x)=x-f(x)$$
Note that
$$a\leq f(x)\leq b,\quad\forall x\in[a,b]$$
Hence,
$$g(a)=a-f(a)\leq 0,\quad g(b)=b-f(b)\geq 0$$
That is, $g(a)\leq0\leq g(b)$, and $g$ is continuous, so we can apply the intermediate value theorem.

For the second part, consider
$$f(x)=1+x$$
on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Try it. If there exists some $c\in[0,\infty)$ with $f(c)=c$, what do you have? By definition of $f$, you have $1+c=c$. Now cancel the $c$'s and you get $1=0$. But as far as I know $1\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, so you can be confident that no such $c$ exists. Hence the result does not hold in this case.

Comment: Don't we have to consider $g(x) = f(x) - x$ instead of $g(x) = x-f(x)$?

Comment: That does not make any difference. In the first case you will apply IVT to $g(a)\geq 0\geq g(b)$ and in the second case to $g(a)\leq 0\leq g(b)$. In any case, the IVT implies that there exists some $c\in[a,b]$ such that $g(c)=0$. Then you have $f(c)=c$ in both cases.