# Proof That g(x)=x

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose there is a function $g$ that is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, where $g(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ and $g^2$$(x) =$ $2 * \int_0^x$$g(t)dt$ for all $x>0$. Prove that $g(x)=x$ for all $x\geq 0$.

What I have so far is that the integral equals $2 * G(x)$, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. But then I cannot think of the next step. I also thought of proving that $g(x) - x = 0$, but I cannot think of what I should do next. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the proof of the fixed point theorem. See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537647/real-analysis-homework-hint.

Comment: @AJR: looks quite different. Notice that in this case we want $g(x) = x$ for *all* $x$.

Comment: @BenMillwood Oh yes, my bad.

Comment: @BenMillwood, agreed and upvote given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall structure of the proof goes along the lines that $g^2$ is differentiable. Since $g$ is stricly positive, it follows that $g$ is differentiable. Also note that we can use the 'First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus', because of the continuity of $g$. Namely, $(2\cdot \int_{0}^{x} g(t)\; dt)' = 2\cdot g(x)$. So, $(g^2)'  = 2g\cdot g' = 2g$. Hence, $g'(x) = 1$ and so $g(x) = x+c$, where $c$ is constant. Since $g^2(0) = 0$, it follows that $g(x) = x$.

Note that my answer is intentionally terse. I leave you to fill in the details.

Comment: Added line of detail for clarity.

Comment: Added second line of detail for completeness.

Comment: Thank you very much for that proof. It had not clicked in my mind that $g^2$$(x)$ was differentiable, but it makes sense. I'm a bit confused about $g^2$$(0)=0$, though. Is that because the lower bound provided by the integral is $0$?

Comment: @HowieTheDuck, yes. $g^2(0) = 2\cdot \int_{0}^{0} g(t)\; dt = 0$. If the lower bound provided by the integral wasn't $0$, then the implication would not be necessarily true.

Comment: True! I had not caught that the bounds would be equal. Very nice. Thank you for your help!