# show that $f$, given by $[f(x)]^2 = 2 \int_0^x f$, is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

The full question reads

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,\infty)$. Suppose that $f(x) \neq 0$ for
>   all $x > 0$ and that $[f(x)]^2 = 2 \int_0^x f$ for all $x \ge 0$.
>   Prove that $f(x)=x$ for all $x \ge 0$.

I'm having trouble showing $f$ is differentiable.

Here's what I've tried. But I'm not confident that this is right.

Let $F(x) = \int_0^x f$. Since $f$ is continuous, by FTC-I, $F(x)$ is differentiable. But $F(x) = \dfrac{[f(x)]^2}{2}$, it follows that $f$ is also differentiable.

Comment: Well... $f^2$ is differentiable since $f^2(x) = 2\int_{0}^{x} f$. Now, you probably want to use the fact that since $f$ is continuous and $f(x) \neq 0$, that $f$ is either strictly positive or strictly negative on $(0,\infty)$. As for your deduction, $f^2$ being differentiable does not mean that $f$ is differentiable. Let $f(x) = |x|$. Then, $f^2(x) = x^2$ is differentiable, but $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Be careful. Knowing that $f^2$ is differentiable does not imply that $f$ is.

Comment: hm... i see what's wrong here. but doesn't differentiating $f^2$ needs $f$ to be differentiable?

Comment: You can't differentiate $f^2(x)$ directly because the chain rule requires $f$ to be differentiate.  However, you have an expression for $f^2$, use that (recall FTC).

Comment: Duplicate of [Proof That g(x)=x](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587501/proof-that-gx-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2\int_0^x f(t) \ dt}$$

and note that the left side is differentiable, so the right side is too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can show that f(x) is differentiable then you can use the fact that $[f(x)]^2=2f(x)f'(x)$ and the derivative of the integral will be $2f(x)$ so we have: $2f(x)f'(x)=2f(x)$ I think that should help on showing what you want.